# Retrieve values from Session in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, linq, gridview, data-binding, session-state

I'm storing Data Source on `Session` as below.

```
var partType = (linq query here);

Session["DataSource"] = partType.ToList();
```

I need to retrieve this and bind to a `gridview`.

```
List<> data = (List<>)Session["DataSource"];

GridView1.DataSource = data;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

What should i give for type of list in  `List<>` ?

Answer (score 0):

IS it that you are storing the datasource in the session variable or storing the values in the session??? 
If you are storing datasource, you need not type cast to list...!!!

Comment: Values. `var partType = (linq query here);`  I'm query database and assign it as above. then store it in session as `Session["DataSource"] = partType.ToList();`

Comment: If the data is you are retrieving is of specific type(class) then write that class in List<SpecificType> else use List<string>

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
var data=Session["DataSource"];
GridView1.DataSource = data;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

your gridview item name should be match list item name.